# Alternative to Mysql that handles increment/decrement with new or existing keys

Tags: database-design

In our application we're looking to store values by ID. In mysql, I might make a table like this:

```
create table balances {
  address bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  balance double NOT NULL
}
```

The problem is how we would interact with it. If I move 15 units from address=5 to address=12, address 12 may not exist. So it takes two or three operations:

```
begin transaction;
subtract 15 from balance where address=5
if address 12 exists
  add 15 to address 12
else
  insert balance=15, address=12
end transaction
```

Is there a database or storage system that is designed for this sort of tracking that could do this sort of operation more atomically without if-checks?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand the use-case, but in MySQL you can use:

```
    INSERT INTO balances (address, balance) VALUES (12, 15)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY 
    UPDATE balance = balance + 15;
```

... so you may not need a specialized DBMS for this sort of thing.

This type of statement is known as 'merge' (as in the SQL standard) or 'upsert'. See this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)) for more info, including details about the implementation in other relational database systems.